# Prove that $a_n=na/(1+n^2 b)$ is strictly decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

given a, b >0

I have tried proving this directly, by setting

$\frac{na}{1+n^2b} > \frac{(n+1)a}{1+(n+1)^2b}$

and end up with

$\frac{na+n^3ab+2n^2ab+nab}{(1+n^b)(1+n^2b+2bn+b)} > \frac{na+a+n^3ab+n^2ab}{(1+n^b)(1+n^2b+2bn+b)}$

I simplify that down to...

$\frac{n^2b+nb}{(1+n^2b)(1+n^2b+2bn+b)} > \frac{1}{(1+n^2b)(1+n^2b+2bn+b)} $

But I have no particular reason to believe that the inequality is true.  Am I making an algebraic error?  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a way to do this by induction?

Thanks!

Comment: This is extremely hard to read. Please see the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here.

Comment: Working on it, just a sec...

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is false when $n$ and $b$ are small enough. For each fixed $b>0$, the sequence is *eventually* decreasing.  ($a$ has no effect, as you saw, because it is just a positive number multiplied with everything.)

Let $f(n)=\dfrac{n}{1+n^2b}$  Then $f(n)=\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{1+n^2b}{n}\right)}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+nb}$.  Thus $f(n+1)<f(n)$ if and only if $\dfrac{1}{n+1}+(n+1)b>\dfrac{1}{n}+nb$ if and only if $b>\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$.  While $b$ can be smaller than that for some $n$ (for an arbitrary finite number of them), the inequality will hold for sufficiently large $n$.

You can get the same conclusion from your work.  At your last inequality, the denominators are equal and positive, so the inequality reduces to $n^2b+nb>1$, which is equivalent to $b>\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

Comment: So the sequence is decreasing only when $b>1/n(n+1)$? Is that a monotone sequence, given that the condition was not given from the beginning?

Comment: @Jamie: It is not really monotone, unless $b>1/2$, but it is *eventually* monotone.  That is, for each $b>0$ there exists $N$ such that $f(n+1)<f(n)$ when $n>N$.  E.g., $N=1/\sqrt{b}$ suffices (although it is not quite optimal in general).

Answer (score 2):

The sequence can only be shown to be *eventually* strictly decreasing.  Take for example $b=\frac{1}{4}$ and $a=1$.  Then we have $a_n=\frac{n}{1+\frac{n^2}{4}}$ so that $a_1=\frac{4}{5}$ and $a_2=1$.  As a hint try treating this as a continuous function $f(x)=\frac{ax}{1+bx^2}$, take the derivative, and try to find a point $x_0$ so that the function is strictly decreasing for all $x>x_0$.  Then think about what you can say about your sequence from this information.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite it as
$$
a_n = \frac{a}{\frac{1}{n} + nb}.
$$
Since $\frac{1}{n} + nb$ is increasing for sufficiently large $n$ and for $b > 0$, it shows $a_n$ must be decreasing for sufficiently large $n$ and for $a > 0$.

To be rigorous we need to say precisely what sufficiently large means and prove it. By sufficiently large, we mean that there is a $B$ such that $n > B$ implies $\frac{1}{n + 1} + (n + 1)b > \frac{1}{n} + nb$. But this is equivalent to $(n + 1)b - nb > \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \iff b > \frac{1}{n(n + 1)}$. But this condition is fulfilled if we have the stronger condition $b > \frac{1}{n^2} \implies n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$. Hence a $B$ that works is $B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$.

Comment: It is not true that $\frac1n+nb$ is always increasing.

Comment: @JonasMeyer You're right. Its only true for sufficiently large $n$. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I fixed my answer.